# Android Fragment Google Maps V2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm developing an app which uses fragment tab, one of my fragment uses Google Maps V2

```
public class AppMapFragment extends Fragment { 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false); 

    try { 
        // Loading map 
        initilizeMap(); 

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    initializePOI(); 

    addMarkers(); 
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); 
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true); 
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
    if (location!=null) { 
            double latitude = location.getLatitude(); 
            double longitude = location.getLongitude(); 
            myPos = new LatLng (latitude, longitude); 
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPos, 15)); 
    } else { 
        // Move the camera instantly to London with a zoom of 15. 
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LONDON, 15)); 
    } 

    // Zoom in, animating the camera. 
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null); 

    return rootView; 
}
```

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#17df0d">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.networkme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" /> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="example.networkme.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.networkme.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.networkme.activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.networkme.activities.InstagramLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="example.networkme.activities.AppSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC0LIYgIxPdlXkb9o7H5ppICC-qTUAykJE" /> 

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

The error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at example.networkme.fragments.AppMapFragment.onCreateView(AppMapFragment.java:41)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
```

I have only copied parts of the error as it is rather long :(.  This error happens whenever I try to run the app.  The line it is referencing to is `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);`.  Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just wondering why do you want to inflate a MapFragmet (which is already a fragment) inside of another fragment!

Comment: My app includes five tabs and one of them is a map.  I thought the way to do that is this :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this implementation, you should as you already did, Create a fragment with a map in it:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
```

create a layout:
**mapview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraZoom="12"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiZoomControls="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="false" />
```

then in the fragment do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
}
```

then to get the map instance:

```
private GoogleMap getGoogleMap() {
        if (map == null && getActivity() != null && getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()!= null) {
            SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
            if (smf != null) {
                map = smf.getMap();
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```